Equivalence time-changed models and stochastic volatility models
I suspect that time changed models can be written as a stochastic volatility model (and vice versa) if the random time is independent of the Brownian motion. Specifically, suppose under the risk-neutral measure
$$
S_T = S_0 e^{\mu T + \beta \tau_T + \nu W_{\tau_T}}
$$
where $\tau_T$ is the random time and is independent of the standard Brownian $W$, then we could say there is some stoch instantaneous vol $\sigma_u$ such that
$$
\tau_T = \int_0^T \sigma_t^2 \, dt
$$
and I think we can fiddle around with $\mu$ such that $S$ is a martingale.
But if $\tau_T$ is not independent of $W$ does anybody know who to write the process for $S$ as a stoch vol process with an `equivalent' stochastic instantaneous vol process $\sigma_u$ with correlation parameter $\rho$?
